# How to copy a method from interface to interface in visual paradigm?

Tags: architecture, visual-paradigm

I'm currently working on a component diagram in Visual Paradigm.
I define interfaces through which the components communicate with each other.
My question is, if it is possible to copy these methods from interface to interface and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

assume you have the model like this, where the interface I1 having an operation ops1.

[image: Interface I1 having an operation]

1. Go to **Diagram** > **New**, and create a **Class Diagram**.
2. Now go to **View** > **Panes** > **Model Explorer**.
   [image: Open Model Explorer]
3. Drag the interface class into daigram
   [image]
4. Right click on the interface class in diagram and select **Move/Copy Members**.
   [image]
5. Add the operation(s) you would like to copy to another interface to the **Selected Operations** list. Select the action as **Copy to**, then choose the target interface class in your project.
   [image]

After that the operation will be duplicate to the target interface class.